# Negation operator (!) used on a recursive call?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I can't figure out how this recursive call works. Using the not operator in the recursive call somehow makes this function determine if the argument given is odd or even. When the '!' is left out fn(2) and fn(5) both return true.

This example is taken out of [JavaScript Allonge free e-book](https://leanpub.com/javascript-allonge/read#named-function-expressions), which, so far has been excellent.

```
var fn = function even(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return true;
}
  else return !even(n - 1);
}

fn(2); //=> true

fn(5); //=> false
```

Comment: Just a side note: this is a really bad use of recursion.  Even checking is just `a % 2 == 0`

Comment: @Mash I'm sure this method is just used as an illustration of recursive logic.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I still think it's better to demonstrate recursion with an actual useful example.  But fair enough.

Comment: This kind of crap is (part of) the reason why people _think_ recursion is slow.  The other big part is pass-by-value, but in compilable languages that have pass by reference, recursion can be fast via tail call optimization (any decent compiler will turn them into an optimized loop).  ... not sure there is a useful situation to use recursion in javascript unless you are operating on global variables.

Comment: @technosaurus recursion in JavaScript is powerful when using it asynchronously because it adds the frame on the next turn of the event loop and removes it from the current stack. So you'll never blow your stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If `n === 0` the result is `true`.
2. If `n > 0` it returns the inverse of `n - 1`.
   If `n === 1` it will return `!even(0)`, or `false`.
   If `n === 2` it will return `!even(1)`, or `!!even(0)`, or `true`.
   If `n === 3` it will return `!even(2)`, or `!!even(1)`, or `!!!even(0)`, or `false`.
   And so on...

In general:

- If `n` is even, the result is inverted an even number number of times, meaning it will return `true`.
- If `n` is odd, the result is inverted an odd number number of times, meaning it will return `false`.

Answer (score 3):

The above function reurns recursively the negation of it self.The base-case is when the number provided becomes zero and each time the function calls it self the number is decreased by one. As a result we have n recursive negations starting with true at base-case (where n is the number provided). For an odd number of negations given true as a starting value you get false as the result and for an even number you get true.
In summary:

1. Starting from given n
2. recursive reduction of n
3. Basecase: n=0 returns true
4. recursive negation of returned value(starting from true at base-case)
   Result:

   - for **odd** number of negations the value returned is **false**
   - for **even** number of negations the value returned is **true**

Lets say we have example  n=5
recursive reduction of n. Values of n at each level:
5
  4
    3
      2
        1
          0 (base-case)
returned values at each level:
          true (base case)
        !true
      !!true
 
    !!!true
  !!!!true
!!!!!true

Answer (score 0):

A variant of you code could be:

```
function even(n) {
  if (n === 0)
    return true;
  else
    return odd(n - 1);
}
function odd(n) {
  if (n === 1)
    return true;
  else
    return even(n - 1);
}
```

We know that all positive numbers starting from 0 alternating between being even and odd. What you example does is defining `odd` to be `!even` which is correct since odd/even are disjoint. In your version using `!`, the `not` needs to be done as a continuation. That means every instance need to do something with the answer after the recursive call returns.